# PHP Doctrine saving and after reading BLOB

Tags: php, image, doctrine, blob

I am saving images into a database with Doctrine, mapped with this:

```
/** @Column(type="blob") **/
protected $data;
```

Everything seems to be OK. I can persist the image data in the database this way:

```
    $largeImage = new ImageData();
    $handle = fopen($imagePath, "r");
    $bytes = fread($handle, filesize($imagePath));
    $largeImage->setData(base64_encode($bytes));
    fclose($handle);

    $entityManager->persist($largeImage);
    $entityManager->flush();
```

OK. The data is saved, but when I need to read it, I can't.

```
var_dump($image->getData());
// outputs resource(1) of type (stream)
```

So, I tried this:

```
$fp = fopen('image.jpg', 'w');
fwrite($fp, base64_decode(stream_get_contents($image->getData())));
fclose($fp);
```

And the contents of the file is not from an image, so the image is not rendered by the Windows photo viewer.

Answer (score 1):

I solved it by doing this:

```
$image = stream_get_contents($image->getData());
$hex = substr($image, 1);
$image =  pack("H*", $hex);

echo $image;
```

my $image content is a hex string started with x, if yours starts with 0x, do: substr($image, 2);